# In EC2, why my Website goes down when I stop httpd on 1 of the 4 instances of elastic loadbalancer?

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

In Amazon EC2, I have 4 instances running a website. Httpd is running in all the instances.

The instances are enabled with load balancer and auto scaling setup.

I have a domain name as myname.tv for my website.

Name the instances as Instance-1, Instance-2, Instance-3, Instance-4.

I see only Instance-1 consuming more memory 13GB then other 3 (1.3GB, 1.2GB, 1.2GB) instances.

```
[root@ip-1 ~]# free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            15G         13G        1.2G         18M        228M        1.2G
Swap:          2.0G        448M        1.6G
[root@ip-1 ~]# 


[root@ip-2 ~]# free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            15G        1.3G         13G         24M        192M         13G
Swap:            0B          0B          0B
[root@ip-2 ~]# 


[root@ip-3 ~]# free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            15G        1.3G         13G         24M        192M         13G
Swap:            0B          0B          0B
[root@ip-3 ~]# 


[root@ip-4 ~]# free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            15G        1.2G         13G         16M        180M         13G
Swap:            0B          0B          0B
[root@ip-4 ~]#
```

I see Only one httpd process is running in Instance-1, which consumes 90% of RAM and 80% of CPU.

I see Multiple httpd Processes are running in Remaining 3 Instances, each httpd process consumes 0.7% of RAM and 20% of CPU.

I see all the four http://IP-1,2,3,4 and a common domain http://myname.tv are working fine.

When I stop httpd in Instance-1, I see the website goes down and I see is currently unavailable error when I access myname.tv, but all other URL's are working fine. That means site is in running state in all other URL's

When I start the httpd the website starts working as usual.

What I need to do?
How to make my website to use all the four instances rather than one?
How to make my website to run even I stop httpd in any one instance?
Why it goes down only for that particular Instance-1?
Please help me to solve this issue?

Thanks
Anand.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What is the Load Balancer saying for the Health Check against each of the EC2 instances? How have you configured your `myname.tv` domain name to point to the Load Balancer? Have you tried accessing from a different computer or browser, to avoid caching issues?

Answer (score 0):

Check the DNS configuration for the domain name that goes down when you take that one server down. It sounds like the DNS is pointing directly to that server instead of pointing to the load balancer.